# update row base on other table row

Tags: mysql, sql

i had sucked at sql query i have 2 tables and 2 rows 1 table is user_sets and second is user_profiles i need to update user_sets row base on row of user_profiles table.
i will give an example.

DB structure

```
table  User_sets
row    n_color_pack
-------------
table  User_profiles
row    gander
---------------------
```

Query:

```
UPDATE user_sets
   SET n_color_pack = 1
  FROM user_profiles, 
       user_sets
  WHERE gander = '0';
```

So as you see, i would like to update User_sets table by setting n_color_pack 1 for everyone who has gender 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `JOIN` the tables to achieve this. Something like this should work (untested):

```
    UPDATE user_sets as s
    INNER JOIN user_profiles as p
    ON s.id = p.id
    SET s.n_color_pack = 1    
    WHERE p.gander = 0
```

Change `s.id`  and `p.id` depending on which column connects the two tables in your case.

*(Credit to ruakh for pointing out my syntax error)*

Comment: @ruakh: Indeed. I was just investigating that myself. Thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, +1. But I think you should link to the doc. :-)